# Iterate throught std::vector inside std::map

Tags: c++, loops, vector, dictionary, iterator

I would appreciate your help on my trouble. I am desperate, feel like idiot, but obviously I cannot figure it out by my self.

I have a vector inside map

```
map<string, vector<string>>SubjectsAndTeachers
```

I have it filled with data such as:

```
[0] = {
  first = "OSY"
  second = size=1 {
    [0] = "lada"
      }
}
[1] = {
  first = "PA1"
  second = size=4 {
    [0] = " honza"
    [1] = "lada"
    [2] = "mirek  "
    [3] = "pepa"
      }
}
[2] = {
  first = "PA2"
  second = size=3 {
    [0] = " honza"
    [1] = "lada"
    [2] = "pepa"
}
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

What it need is simply, iterate all of them to print them into console. So far I have came up with:

```
for(map<string, vector<string> >::const_iterator it = SubjectsAndTeachers.begin();  it != SubjectsAndTeachers.end(); ++it)
{
    cout << it->first << ": ";
    for (vector<string>::const_iterator b = it->second.begin(); b != it->second.end() ;++it)
    {
        cout << *b;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

I am trying to get:

```
OSY : lada
PA1 : honza lada mirek pepa
     .
     .
     .
     .
```

But this doesnt seem to work.

Please could someone help?

Comment: How does it not "work"?

Comment: I get seg faul here:  `template <class _NodePtr>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
_NodePtr
__tree_min(_NodePtr __x) _NOEXCEPT
{
    while (__x->__left_ != nullptr)
        __x = __x->__left_;
    return __x;
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You second loop look suspicious:

```
for (vector<string>::const_iterator b = it->second.begin(); b != it->second.end() ;++it)
                                                                                   ^^^^
```

You certainly mean `++b`...

Comment: OOOOH MY GOD, Thank you very much!!! I have totaly overlooked that mistype. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

To simplify the task you could use the range based for statemeent. For example

```
for ( const auto &p : SubjectsAndTeachers )
{
    cout << p.first << " :";
    for ( const auto &s : p.second )
    {
        cout << ' ' << s;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

As for your code then you increment iterator it in the inner loop instead of iterator b.

Comment: Your solution looks nice, I might use this in further implementation, thank you.